# Proximity cell using Raster package in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I want to find the neighbor cells number and their values to the given cell location in the raster object. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You are more likely to get a useful answer by adhering to some of the advice provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Have a look at `raster::adjacent()` . It should do what you need.